# Bash: For Each Line in a File, Set variable

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to iterate through a text file, and set a variable once for each line.

I am having trouble doing so. I have simplified the process so that it is just echoing the result. There would be more going one, but this part of the widget is not working correctly.

```
while read p; do
   set $FN=`echo $p`
   echo $FN
done <file.txt
```

When I don't use set, it looks like it is trying to echo a file called the contents of $p.

I am using echo $p to send the line to a series of cuts, to get the data I want.

I know I am doing something fundamentally wrong, just not sure what that might be.

Comment: `$p` contains the contents of the line - to assign that to another variable, use `FN=$p`. You don't need `set` here. I think your example might be oversimplified, and that we can probably help you more if you show us a sample of your file and the desired output.

Comment: By the way, always quote your variables - in your example, that would be `FN=$(echo "$p")` and `echo "$FN"`.

Comment: Also note that `$FN` refers to the _value_ of the variable called `FN`, so `FN=$p`, not `set $FN=...` or `$FN=...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me. Just say "FN=" without the "set

```
while read p; do
  FN=$p
  echo $FN
done < test.list
```

Comment: Note that this loses the leading and trailing spaces on the line, and also outputs $FN after applying word splitting and glob expansion to it.

Comment: Yeah. There will be some tidying up to do. But isn't that always the case with shell work ;) ?

Comment: it doesn't have to be, if you changed the first statement to `IFS= while read -r p` and quoted `$FN` it'd solve the problems I mentioned.

Comment: Sure, I'm not disagreeing with your technical analysis. The problem is that, in my experience, if you're trying to explain something in shell programming, the syntactic fluff that you need to deal with situations that aren't immediately predictable (spaces in filenames, globbing, etc) can obscure the main point you're trying to make.

Comment: Yeah, it's more complicated, but I don't think that sharing potentially broken examples is the solution, especially in the case where your answer is "just remove the `set`", implying that everything else is fine!